# DocumentTermMatrix in r: maxWordLength doesn't work?

Tags: sparse-matrix, tm

The maxWordLength argument in DocumentTermMatrix doesn't seem to have any effect (no warnings, no errors). I'm using tm_0.6-2. R version 3.2.2 mac. Any ideas?

df <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(as.character("this is my test string with an exceptionally long word"))))
df.dtf <- DocumentTermMatrix(df,  control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer, minWordLength=2,maxWordLength=4, minDocFreq=minFreq))

inspect(df.dtf)

yields:

> inspect(df.dtf)
>   <>
>   Non-/sparse entries: 7/0
>   Sparsity           : 0%
>   Maximal term length: 13
>   Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

```
Terms
```

Docs exceptionally long string test this with word
   1             1    1      1    1    1    1    1

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, if I understood you correct and you just want to 'limit' your maximum word length:

```
df.dtf <- DocumentTermMatrix(df, control = list( wordLengths=c(1,4)))
```